# How do I stop <div> tags interfering with counters?

Tags: html, css, css-counter

In the code below, I need to use the `div` tag at the top of the HTML for styling. Without the `div` tag in place, the `hx` tags are outline numbered correctly, but with the `div` in place everything goes completely wrong. I need [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVqEpX) to work like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpGjRb), but with the `div` tag still in place, and I need it to work for divs with different ids. Any ideas?

```css
body {counter-reset: h1}
h1 {counter-reset: h2}
h2 {counter-reset: h3}

h1:before {counter-increment: h1; content: counter(h1) ". "}
h2:before {counter-increment: h2; content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) ". "}
h3:before {counter-increment: h3; content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) "." counter(h3) ". "}
```

```html
<div class="varies">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1>
</div>
<p>Morbi efficitur nibh metus, a vehicula mauris tristique ac. Duis ornare metus eget iaculis hendrerit.</p>
  <h2>Morbi nisi lacus, ultricies sit amet turpis a, aliquet congue nulla.</h2>
        <p>Duis eget facilisis nisl.</p>
    <h3>Donec tincidunt purus quam, ut accumsan lorem hendrerit a.</h3>
      <p>Aenean in mattis quam.</p>
    <h3>Maecenas a nulla sit amet ligula facilisis tincidunt lacinia non enim.</h3>
      <p>Aliquam dignissim turpis placerat, facilisis magna et, venenatis purus.</p>
  <h2>Suspendisse tempus eu elit nec malesuada.</h2>
        <p>In ut sollicitudin nisi. Praesent non porttitor ante, molestie scelerisque mauris.</p>
  <h2>Vivamus eu turpis efficitur, ornare risus in, consectetur tellus.</h2>
        <p>Cras pellentesque orci eu placerat mollis.</p>      
<h1>Duis eu nulla et tellus porttitor auctor.</h1>
```

Comment: Can't you set the class to the `h1` directly, without the div?

Comment: Counters are ultra sensitive when it comes to levels. Though I can't provide a concrete explanation on why `h2` counter fails but `h3` counter works in the above scenario, it would always be better to reset all counters once in `body` itself like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gkzLj4gL/). I am not adding as answer because I can't explain why it happens this way.

Comment: @LcSalazar Unfortunately, for various reasons, I can't do that. I think it would've worked though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason for the behavior can be explained in detail by having a look at what the [W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-lists-3/#creating-counters) say about creation of counters, their scope and inheritance.

> **Counter Reset:** The counter-reset property creates new counters on an element.
>
> **Scope of a Counter:** The scope of a counter starts at the first element in the document that has a 'counter-reset' for that counter.
>
> **Counter Inheritance:** A counter and its value are inherited separately, possibly from different elements. If an element has a previous sibling, it must inherit all of the sibling’s counters. Otherwise, if the element has a parent, it must inherit all of the parent’s counters. Otherwise, the element must have an empty set of counters. The element then inherits counter values from the immediately preceding element **in document order**.

---

#### Why does the snippet without div work?

In the working snippet (the one without the `div`), the following is what happens:

- `counter.h1` (added a prefix to differentiate from element) is created (or reset) at `body` and its initial value is set as 0.
- All elements inherit their parent's counters and so every element within `body` gets `counter.h1`. When the first `h1` is encountered, the value of `counter.h1` is incremented to 1. When the next `h1` is encountered, it inherits counter value from the previous element and then increments to 2.
- `counter.h2` counter is created at `h1` element and value is set to 0. This value is visible to the siblings of the `h1` and they can all inherit it.
- In this snippet, all `h2` elements are actually siblings of the `h1` element and so each `h2` element inherits `counter.h2` that was already created at the `h1` and just increments its value. So, when the first `h2` is encountered `counter.h2` becomes 1 and so on.
- Similar to `h2` elements, the `h3` elements are also siblings of both the `h1` and `h2` elements and so they also inherit `counter.h1` and `counter.h2`. This is why the numbering remains correct in this sample.

```css
body {counter-reset: h1}
h1 {counter-reset: h2}
h2 {counter-reset: h3}
h1:before {counter-increment: h1; content: counter(h1)". "}
h2:before {counter-increment: h2; content: counter(h1)"." counter(h2)". "}
h3:before {counter-increment: h3; content: counter(h1)"." counter(h2)"." counter(h3)". "}
```

```html
<!-- body creates counter.h1 and set to 0 -->
<h1>Heading 1 <!-- Inherits counter.h1 from parent, creates counter.h2 and set to 0 -->
  <!-- ::before being a child inherits all counters from parent, increments counter.h1 to 1 and displays value -->
</h1>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h2>Heading 2 <!-- Inherits counter.h1, counter.h2 from sibling, creates counter.h3 and set to 0 -->
  <!-- ::before being a child inherits all counters from parent, increments counter.h2 to 1 and displays value -->
</h2>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h3>Heading 3 <!-- Inherits counter.h1, counter.h2, counter.h3 -->
  <!-- ::before being a child inherits all counters from parent, increments counter.h3 to 1 and displays value -->
</h3>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h3>2nd Heading 3 <!-- Inherits counter.h1, counter.h2, counter.h3 -->
  <!-- ::before being a child inherits all counters from parent, increments counter.h3 to 2 and displays value -->  
</h3>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h2>2nd Heading 2 <!-- Inherits counter.h1, counter.h2, counter.h3, resets counter.h3 to 0 -->
  <!-- ::before being a child inherits all counters from parent, increments counter.h2 to 2 and displays value -->
</h2>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h2>3rd Heading 2 <!-- Inherits counter.h1, counter.h2, counter.h3, resets counter.h3 to 0 -->
  <!-- ::before being a child inherits all counters from parent, increments counter.h2 to 3 and displays value -->
</h2>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h1>2nd Heading 1 <!-- Inherits counter.h1, counter.h2, counter.h3, resets counter.h2 to 0 -->
  <!-- ::before being a child inherits all counters from parent, increments counter.h1 to 2 and displays value -->
</h1>
```

---

#### Why does the snippet with div not work?

Now let us to come to the snippet that doesn't work (the one where the `h1` is present within a `div`).

- Here, the `h1` creates `counter.h2` but this can be inherited only by the siblings of the `h1` (of which there are none).
- Whenever a `h2` element is encountered, UA tries to increment value of `counter.h2` within the `:before` selector. But here the `h2` parent does not inherit `counter.h2` and hence `h2:before` doesn't either. Because of this `h2:before` will create its own `counter.h2` and increment to 1.
- Subsequent `h2` elements also cannot inherit `counter.h2` because the counter is created by `h2:before` (which is a child of `h2`). Because of this, each time a `h2` is encountered a new counter is created within its `:before` and incremented. This is why all `h2` show up as **1.1**.
- Similarly, none of the `h3` elements know about `counter.h2` and they don't increment it either and this is why they show up as **1.0.x**.
- However, they all can inherit `counter.h3` because it was created by `h2` element which is a sibling of all `h3` elements. This is why `counter.h3` gets incremented properly.

```css
body {counter-reset: h1}
h1 {counter-reset: h2}
h2 {counter-reset: h3}
h1:before {counter-increment: h1; content: counter(h1)". "}
h2:before {counter-increment: h2; content: counter(h1)"." counter(h2)". "}
h3:before {counter-increment: h3; content: counter(h1)"." counter(h2)"." counter(h3)". "}
```

```html
<!-- body creates counter.h1, sets it to 0 -->
<div class="test"> <!-- Inherits counter.h1 from parent -->
  <h1>Heading 1 <!-- Again inherits counter.h1 from parent, creates counter.h2 -->
    <!-- ::before increments counter.h1 to 1 and display value-->
  </h1>
</div>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h2>Heading 2 <!-- Inherits counter.h1 as it is from parent but not counter.h2, creates counter.h3 -->
  <!-- ::before has no counter.h2, so creates a counter.h2 and increments to 1 -->
</h2>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h3>Heading 3 <!-- Inherits counter.h1 as it is from parent, couunter.h3 from sibling but not counter.h2 -->
  <!-- ::before inherits counter.h3 from parent and increments to 1, has no counter.h2 so creates a new counter.h2 and sets to 0 -->
</h3>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h3>2nd Heading 3 <!-- Inherits counter.h1 as it is from parent, couunter.h3 from sibling but not counter.h2 -->
  <!-- ::before inherits counter.h3 from parent and increments to 2, has no counter.h2 so creates a new counter.h2 and sets to 0 -->
</h3>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h2>2nd Heading 2 <!-- Inherits counter.h1 as it is from parent, couunter.h3 from sibling but not counter.h2, resets counter.h3 to 0 -->
  <!-- ::before has no counter.h2, so creates a counter.h2 and increments to 1 -->
</h2>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h2>3rd Heading 2 <!-- Inherits counter.h1 as it is from parent, couunter.h3 from sibling but not counter.h2, resets counter.h3 to 0 -->
  <!-- ::before has no counter.h2, so creates a counter.h2 and increments to 1 -->
</h2>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h1>2nd Heading 1 <!-- Inherits counter.h1 as it is from parent, couunter.h3 from sibling but not counter.h2, resets counter.h2 to 0 -->
  <!-- ::before inherits counter.h1 from parent and increments to 2 -->
</h1>
```

---

#### What is the solution?

Ideal solution to this problem would be to reset all 3 counters first at body itself so that all elements are aware of the existence of a counter and can inherit or use its value.

```css
body {counter-reset: h1 h2 h3}
h1 {counter-reset: h2 h3}
h2 {counter-reset: h3}
h1:before {counter-increment: h1; content: counter(h1)". "}
h2:before {counter-increment: h2; content: counter(h1)"." counter(h2)". "}
h3:before {counter-increment: h3; content: counter(h1)"." counter(h2)"." counter(h3)". "}
```

```html
<!-- body creates counter.h1, counter.h2, counter.h3 sets all 0 -->
<div class="test"> <!-- Inherits all 3 counters -->
  <h1>Heading 1 <!-- Inherits all 3 counters, resets counter.h2 and counter.h3 to 0 -->
    <!-- ::before also inherits all 3 counters, increments counter.h1 to 1 and displays value -->
  </h1>
</div>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h2>Heading 2 <!-- Inherits all 3 counters, resets counter.h3 to 0 -->
  <!-- ::before also inherits all 3 counters, increments counter.h2 to 1 and displays value -->
</h2>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h3>Heading 3 <!-- Inherits all 3 counters -->
  <!-- ::before also inherits all 3 counters, increments counter.h3 to 1 and displays value -->
</h3>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h3>2nd Heading 3 <!-- Inherits all 3 counters -->
  <!-- ::before also inherits all 3 counters, increments counter.h3 to 2 and displays value -->
</h3>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h2>2nd Heading 2 <!-- Inherits all 3 counters, resets counter.h3 to 0 -->
  <!-- ::before also inherits all 3 counters, increments counter.h2 to 2, resets counter.h3 to 0 and displays value -->
</h2>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h2>3rd Heading 2 <!-- Inherits all 3 counters, resets counter.h3 to 0 -->
  <!-- ::before also inherits all 3 counters, increments counter.h2 to 3, resets counter.h3 to 0 and displays value -->
</h2>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<h1>2nd Heading 1 <!-- Inherits all 3 counters, resets counter.h2 and counter.h3 to 0 -->
  <!-- ::before also inherits all 3 counters, increments counter.h1 to 2, resets counter.h2, counter.h3 to 0 and displays value -->
</h1>
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider this (very similar to your structure, just a bit simpler):

```css
body {
  counter-reset: h1;
}

h1:before { 
  content: counter(h1) ". ";
  counter-increment: h1;
}
h1 {
  counter-reset: h2;
}

h2:before {
  content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) ". ";
  counter-increment: h2;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Heading first level 1</h1>
</div>
  <h2>Heading second level 1</h2>
  <h2>Heading second level 2</h2>
  <h2>Heading second level 3</h2>
  <h2>Heading second level 4</h2>
  <h2>Heading second level 5</h2>    
<h1>Heading first level 2</h1>
  <h2>Test</h2>
  <h2>Test</h2>
  <h2>Test</h2>
<h1>Heading first level 3</h1>
<h1>Heading first level 4</h1>
```

## Why your layout does not work

By recommendation:

> Counters are "self-nesting", in the sense that resetting a counter in
>   a descendant element or pseudo-element automatically creates a new
>   instance of the counter. This is important for situations like lists
>   in HTML, where elements can be nested inside themselves to arbitrary
>   depth.

The problem in your layout is that the first `<h1>` inside the `<div>` initializes a separate instance of the `h1` counter. That happens because counters are sensitive to nested elements. Every time you reset a counter in a different level, that does not affect the same counter instance scoped into another level!

### What happens

Following is what happens:

```
01. <body>                             | h1 = *
02. <div>                              |
03.   <h1>Heading first level 1</h1>   | h1 = 1 |  div-h2 = *
04. </div>                             |
05.   <h2>Heading second level 1</h2>  |        | h2 = 1
06.   <h2>Heading second level 2</h2>  |        | h2 = 1
07.   <h2>Heading second level 3</h2>  |        | h2 = 1
08.   <h2>Heading second level 4</h2>  |        | h2 = 1
09.   <h2>Heading second level 5</h2>  |        | h2 = 1
10. <h1>Heading first level 2</h1>     | h1 = 2 | h2 = *
11.   <h2>Test</h2>                    |        | h2 = 1
12.   <h2>Test</h2>                    |        | h2 = 2
13.   <h2>Test</h2>                    |        | h2 = 3
14. <h1>Heading first level 3</h1>     | h1 = 3
15. <h1>Heading first level 4</h1>     | h1 = 4
```

As you can see, in `01.` we reset counter `h1` which is working fine. However in `h1` elements we reset counter `h2`.

The problem occurs in `03.` where we reset counter `h2` in nested level `div`, to clarify this, I call this counter: `div-h2`. In fact, next `h2` elements from `05.` to `09.` are using a different counter which **has not been reset**! That is counter `h2` (no nesting) and even if they try to increment it, there is nothing to increment as a reset is mandatory!

In `10.` we do not have a `div` nesting, thus counter `h2` is correctly reset, thus incremented as well.

### What to do

In your case, you must avoid generating nested structures that are not homogeneous in your page. This is a suggestion to have a clean HTML, in your case, if you really need to keep that div, just add a `div` selector where you reset counter `h2`:

```
div {
  counter-reset: h2;
}
```

So here is the final working snippet:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: h1;
}

h1:before { 
  content: counter(h1) ". ";
  counter-increment: h1;
}
h1 {
  counter-reset: h2;
}

div {
  counter-reset: h2;
}

h2:before {
  content: counter(h1) "." counter(h2) ". ";
  counter-increment: h2;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Heading first level 1</h1>
</div>
  <h2>Heading second level 1</h2>
  <h2>Heading second level 2</h2>
  <h2>Heading second level 3</h2>
  <h2>Heading second level 4</h2>
  <h2>Heading second level 5</h2>    
<h1>Heading first level 2</h1>
  <h2>Test</h2>
  <h2>Test</h2>
  <h2>Test</h2>
<div>
  <h1>Heading first level 1</h1>
</div>
  <h2>Test</h2>
  <h2>Test</h2>
  <h2>Test</h2>
<h1>Heading first level 3</h1>
<h1>Heading first level 4</h1>
```

The solution above works if you only have those `div` nesting for `h1`, in case you expect to have other header elements wrapped into `div`s, than you need to reset `h3` counter there too! But I do not recommend this because it is a very messy CSS arrangement: hard to maintain and not easy to follow.

Remember in CSS there is always a way to achieve things, you said you need that `div`, but I think you did not try all possibilities to get rid of it.

Comment: Unfortunately that breaks when anything beyond the first `h1` tag is inside a `div` see e.g.: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGmgKK. The heading labelled "Test" should be 2.1, not 2.6.

Comment: I must say one thing... I believed that acting in pseudo-elements was a wrong approach, but i can actually see (in W3C recommendation) that doing counter increment in pseudo-elements is fine!

Comment: Actually this behavior is not because of self nesting nature. As per spec -*Counters are "self-nesting"; creating a new counter in an element which already has a counter with the same name simply creates a new counter of the same name, nested inside the existing counter.* Here the h1 within div doesn't have a counter with same name. The issue here is to do with creation and inheritance of counters.