# Numbering h1, h2, h3 with CSS, with presence of article tag

Tags: css, css-counter

I have this kink of code, where HTML is generated by
[hieroglyph](https://github.com/nyergler/hieroglyph), and CSS is provided by
me:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

body {
    counter-reset: chapter 3 section 0;
}

h2 {
    counter-reset: slide 0;
    counter-increment: section;
}
h3 {
    counter-increment: slide;
}


h1:before {
    content: counter(chapter) ". ";
}
h2:before {
    content: counter(chapter) "." counter(section) " ";
}
h3:before {
    content: counter(chapter) "." counter(section) "." counter(slide) " ";
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<article> <h1>chapter</h1> </article>

<article> <h2>section A</h2> </article>
<article> <h3> slide a</h3> </article>
<article> <h3> slide b</h3> </article>

<article> <h2>section B</h2> </article>
<article> <h3> slide a</h3> </article>
<article> <h3> slide b</h3> </article>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to number h1/h2/h3 (which I name chapter, section, slide), but
`article` tag make it difficult.

How can I fix the CSS rules, in order to see:

```
3. chapter
3.1 section A
3.1.1 side a
3.1.2 side b
3.2 section B
3.2.1 side a
3.2.2 side b
```

Instead of (`h3` are wrongly numbered):

```
3. chapter
3.1 section A
3.1.1 side a
3.1.1 side b
3.2 section B
3.2.1 side a
3.2.1 side b
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of (or related to) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658111/how-do-i-stop-div-tags-interfering-with-counters/31660287#31660287. The reason for numbering is because of how the `h3` are not within the same parent. You need to have a relook at the document structure because with the current way, it wouldn't work even if you reset all counters at `body` like mentioned in that answer (to be continued...)

Comment: Even if you do `counter-reset: slide 0` at `body` what would happen is all the `h3` would get continuous numbering because the `h2` which resets it back to 0 is under a different parent.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'll try to implement it in JavaScript instead of CSS.

Comment: Nope mate. It seems like you've either got to change the structure (or) add classes to the `article` tag like [**in this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2q7j0pjw/) (or) use scripting.

Comment: Thanks Harry! I think I can use your solution with classes. Here is my [scripting solution](http://jsfiddle.net/dfroger/bm8ye22y/1/)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I just accepted the answer. I'll review the two answers more completly soon.

Comment: Oh sure @DavidFroger That is fine. Actually you could have chosen an answer after completing the review also :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reasons:**

As I had described in my comment to the question, CSS counters are very sensitive to levels and the document structure. If the structure doesn't match a certain pattern then it will affect the entire working of the counters. This is because of how elements inherit the counters and the counter's value. Details about how the counters work, how they are inherited is described in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658111/how-do-i-stop-div-tags-interfering-with-counters/31660287#31660287).

For the sake of more clarity, I have added inline comments in the below snippet to explain the working:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: chapter 3 section 0;
}
h2 {
  counter-reset: slide 0;
  counter-increment: section;
}
h3 {
  counter-increment: slide;
}
h1:before {
  content: counter(chapter)". ";
}
h2:before {
  content: counter(chapter)"." counter(section)" ";
}
h3:before {
  content: counter(chapter)"." counter(section)"." counter(slide)" ";
}
```

```html
<!-- body creates chapter, section counters -->
<article> <!-- this inherits both counters from its parent and also its value because it is the previous element in document order -->
  <h1>chapter</h1> <!-- inherits both counters and their value from parent -->
</article>

<article> <!-- this inherits both chapter and section counters from parent (body) and the value for the counters from the previous sibling -->
  <h2>section A</h2> <!-- inherits both counters, increments section to 1, creates slide counter. slide counter is visible only to this element but not parent -->
</article>
<article> <!-- this inherits both chapter and section counters from parent (body) and the value for the counters from the previous sibling -->
  <h3> slide a</h3> <!-- inherits chapter, section but sees no slide counter and hence creates a new slide counter and increments to 1, the parent doesn't know about this new slide counter -->
</article>
<article> <!-- this inherits both chapter and section counters from parent (body) and the value for the counters from the previous sibling -->
  <h3> slide b</h3> <!-- inherits chapter, section but sees no slide counter and hence creates a new slide counter and increments to 1, the parent doesn't know about this new slide counter -->
</article>

<article> <!-- this inherits both chapter and section counters from parent (body) and the value for the counters from the previous sibling -->
  <h2>section B</h2>  <!-- inherits both counters, increments section to 2, creates slide counter. slide counter is visible only to this element but not parent -->
</article>
<article> <!-- this inherits both chapter and section counters from parent (body) and the value for the counters from the previous sibling -->
  <h3> slide a</h3> <!-- inherits chapter, section but sees no slide counter and hence creates a new slide counter and increments to 1, the parent doesn't know about this new slide counter --> 
</article>
<article> <!-- this inherits both chapter and section counters from parent (body) and the value for the counters from the previous sibling -->
  <h3> slide b</h3> <!-- inherits chapter, section but sees no slide counter and hence creates a new slide counter and increments to 1, the parent doesn't know about this new slide counter --> 
</article>
```

However the solution described in the linked thread would still not work for this case because of how the document is structured. Even if we reset the `slide` counter at body and make the counter visible to all child elements, the reset to 0 happens only when a `h2` is encountered. Since all `h2` are inside their respective `article` and the `article` (and thereby the child `h2`) already have `slide` counter inherited from their parent, another reset at a different level possibly results in self nesting (that is, new `slide` counter being created nested under the parent `slide`). Because of it, subsequent reset have no effect and the `h3` elements keep continuing the numbering as seen in the below snippet:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: chapter 3 section 0 slide 0;
}
h2 {
  counter-reset: slide 0;
  counter-increment: section;
}
h3 {
  counter-increment: slide;
}
h1:before {
  content: counter(chapter)". ";
}
h2:before {
  content: counter(chapter)"." counter(section)" ";
}
h3:before {
  content: counter(chapter)"." counter(section)"." counter(slide)" ";
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>chapter</h1>
</article>
<article>
  <h2>section A</h2>
</article>
<article>
  <h3> slide a</h3>
</article>
<article>
  <h3> slide b</h3>
</article>
<article>
  <h2>section B</h2>
</article>
<article>
  <h3> slide a</h3>
</article>
<article>
  <h3> slide b</h3>
</article>
```

---

**Solution:**

There are three solutions to this  situation and they are as follows:

1. Change the document structure to have the `h3` elements grouped under the same `article` like in the below snippet.

   ```css
   body {
     counter-reset: chapter 3 section 0;
   }
   h2 {
     counter-reset: slide 0;
     counter-increment: section;
   }
   h3 {
     counter-increment: slide;
   }
   h1:before {
     content: counter(chapter)". ";
   }
   h2:before {
     content: counter(chapter)"." counter(section)" ";
   }
   h3:before {
     content: counter(chapter)"." counter(section)"." counter(slide)" ";
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <article>
     <h1>chapter</h1>
   </article>
   <article>
     <h2>section A</h2> <!-- The reset here has no effect because it creates a different instance -->
   </article>
   <article>
     <h3> slide a</h3> <!-- Parent doesn't have slide counter, so this creates one and increments it to 1 -->
     <h3> slide b</h3> <!-- This inherits slide counter's value fom previous element and increments to 2 -->
   </article>
   <article>
     <h2>section A</h2> <!-- The reset here has no effect because it creates a different instance -->
   </article>
   <article>
     <h3> slide a</h3> <!-- Parent doesn't have slide counter, so this creates one and increments it to 1 -->
     <h3> slide b</h3> <!-- This inherits slide counter's value fom previous element and increments to 2 -->
   </article>
   ```
2. Give each `article` a class which indicates what it contains and then do the `counter-reset` or `counter-increment` at the parent level itself. This means the counters and their values would be visible to all siblings. This in my opinion is the **best approach** without modifying your structure.

   ```css
   .h1-container {
     counter-reset: chapter 3 section 0 slide 0;
   }
   .h2-container {
     counter-reset: slide 0;
     counter-increment: section;
   }
   .h3-container {
     counter-increment: slide;
   }
   h1:before {
     content: counter(chapter)". ";
   }
   h2:before {
     content: counter(chapter)"." counter(section)" ";
   }
   h3:before {
     content: counter(chapter)"." counter(section)"." counter(slide)" ";
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <article class='h1-container'>
     <h1>chapter</h1>
   </article>
   <article class='h2-container'>
     <h2>section A</h2>
   </article>
   <article class='h3-container'>
     <h3> slide a</h3>
   </article>
   <article class='h3-container'>
     <h3> slide b</h3>
   </article>
   <article class='h2-container'>
     <h2>section A</h2>
   </article>
   <article class='h3-container'>
     <h3> slide a</h3>
   </article>
   <article class='h3-container'>
     <h3> slide b</h3>
   </article>
   ```
3. Use JavaScript or jQuery (or other preferred libraries) to count the elements and set numbering according to it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this. No JavaScript; HTML markup the same as you had originally.

```css
body {
  counter-reset: chapter 3 section 0 slide 2;
}

h2 {
  counter-increment: slide -2 section;
}

h3 {
  counter-increment: slide;
}

h1:before {
  content: counter(chapter)". ";
}

h2:before {
  content: counter(chapter)"." counter(section)" ";
}

h3:before {
  content: counter(chapter)"." counter(section)"." counter(slide)" ";
}
```

```html
<article> <h1>chapter</h1> </article>

<article> <h2>section A</h2> </article>
<article> <h3> slide a</h3> </article>
<article> <h3> slide b</h3> </article>

<article> <h2>section B</h2> </article>
<article> <h3> slide a</h3> </article>
<article> <h3> slide b</h3> </article>
```

It works by not doing a `counter-reset`, but a `counter-increment` for the `slide` counter, thus keeping the counter global. However, there's a catch: it works only when the number of slides is fixed (in this case, 2).

Answer (score 0):

I've been needing this question to validate a list in a pdf, however I had difficulty using it the way it was made available here, since as the h1 was not implemented in the css it does not count.
Anyway, there is a solution that I adapted for myself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  counter-reset: chapter 0 section 0;
}
h1{
    counter-increment: chapter;
}
h2 {
  counter-reset: slide 0;
  counter-increment: section;
}
h3 {
  counter-increment: slide;
}
h1:before {
  content: counter(chapter)". ";
}
h2:before {
  content: counter(chapter)"." counter(section)" ";
}
h3:before {
  content: counter(chapter)"." counter(section)"." counter(slide)" ";
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<p>This paragraph is styled with CSS.</p>
<h2>Test</h2>
<p>CSS comments are not shown in the output.</p>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<p>This paragraph is styled with CSS.</p>

</body>
</html>
```