# Counter does not increment in CSS

Tags: css, css-counter

In this example:

```css
h3 {
  font-size: .9em;
  counter-reset: section;
}
h4 {
  font-size: .7em;
  counter-reset: subsection;
}
h3:before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section)" ";
}
h4:before {
  counter-increment: subsection 2;
  content: counter(section)"." counter(subsection)" ";
}
```

```html
<h3>Favorite Movies</h3>
<h4>District 9</h4>
<h4>The Matrix</h4>
<h4>The Cabin in the Woods</h4>

<h3>Others</h3>
<h4>Minority Report</h4>
<h4>Lord of the Rings</h4>
<h4>Fargo</h4>
```

I see that `section` and `subsection` does not increment.

What is the problem in this code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The counters are not incrementing properly because you're resetting them in their own parent.

For example, the counter `section` is being reset (that is, the value is set to 0) every time the browser encounters a `h3` tag and so when the `counter-increment` is being called within `h3:before` (children of `h3`), it just increments from 0 to 1 every time.

You should reset the counters at the grand parent level (or at `body` if there is no grand parent).

```css
body {
  counter-reset: section;
}
h3 {
  font-size: .9em;
  counter-reset: subsection;
}
h4 {
  font-size: .7em;
}
h3:before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section)" ";
}
h4:before {
  counter-increment: subsection 2;
  content: counter(section)"." counter(subsection)" ";
}
```

```html
<!-- at body reset section to 0 -->

<h3>
  <!-- the h3 will inherit counter section from body (its parent) and increment to 1 in :before -->
  <!-- every time a h3 is encountered, the subsection is reset to 0 -->
  Favorite Movies
</h3>
<h4>
  <!-- this inherits subsection counter from previous sibling and increments value to 2 in :before -->
  District 9
</h4>
<h4>
  <!-- this inherits subsection counter and its value from previous sibling and increments value to 4 in :before -->
  The Matrix
</h4>
<h4>
  <!-- this inherits subsection counter and its value from previous sibling and increments value to 6 in :before -->
  The Cabin in the Woods
</h4>

<h3>
  <!-- the h3 will inherit counter section from body (its parent), its value from the previous sibling and increment to 2 in :before -->
  <!-- here the subsection counter is again reset to 0 because the subsection numbering has to restart -->
  Others
</h3>
<h4>
  <!-- this inherits subsection counter from previous sibling and increments value to 2 in :before -->
  Minority Report
</h4>
<h4>
  <!-- this inherits subsection counter and its value from previous sibling and increments value to 4 in :before -->  
  Lord of the Rings
</h4>
<h4>
  <!-- this inherits subsection counter and its value from previous sibling and increments value to 6 in :before -->  
  Fargo
</h4>
```

Comment: from previous sibling? Is `h3` sibling of `h4`?

Comment: @overexchange: Each element would inherit the counters and values from previous siblings, so the value of the section counter would be carried over to all `h4` elements also. I left it out for brevity. You can find a very detailed explanation of counter inheritance in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658111/how-do-i-stop-div-tags-interfering-with-counters/31660287#31660287). And yes, the second `h3` is a sibling of `h4` as per the structure in question. Elements are siblings as long as they share the same parent. Here the parent for both `h3` and `h4` is `body`.

Comment: As far as I can tell, counters get relatively less attention than other CSS properties. This is due most likely to relatively less use. But @Harry's answers are very useful and helpful. Good question, good answer. Thanks both.

Comment: @Michael_B How do you number list items?

Comment: @overexchange, I use default numbering or `start` attribute. I've never used counters in production and am not an expert. Hence, I appreciate reading these questions and answers, which are useful lessons.

Answer (score 0):

For me it only started incrementing the subsection after resetting subsection within body, too, both within one line:

```
counter-reset: ctrPos ctrSubPos;
```

Alas, I could still not reset the subsection counter.
Tested on current chromium and Firefox 104.0.1.