# Using CSS counters to create sub-sections with a counter-reset

Tags: html, css, css-counter

I'm trying to get CSS counters to increment items that indicate sub-items.  Perhaps because the HTML is not nested, the reset doesn't look like it's working as I'd expect.  Can anyone help me understand why?  If I reset the `sub-item` counter in the body selector, all the sub-items get treated just like the items, ignoring the second reset.

CSS definitions:

```
body {
  counter-reset: panel item;
  font-family: monospace;
}

div.panel-heading:before {
  counter-increment: panel;
  content: "Panel " counter(panel, upper-roman) ". ";
}

div.panel-body div.item:before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: "Item " counter(item) ". ";
  counter-reset: sub-item;
}

div.panel-body div.sub-item:before {
  counter-increment: sub-item;
  content: "sub-item " counter(item) counter(sub-item, lower-alpha) ". ";
}
```

HTML body:

```
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    &lt;- should be I </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="item">
      &lt;- should be 1
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item">
      &lt;- should be 1a
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item">
      &lt;- should be 1b
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item">
      &lt;- should be 1c
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      &lt;- should be 2
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item">
      &lt;- should be 2a
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item">
      &lt;- should be 2b
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    &lt;- should be II </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="item">
      &lt;- should be 3
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item">
      &lt;- should be 3a
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      &lt;- should be 4
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item">
      &lt;- should be 4a
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item">
      &lt;- should be 4b
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item">
      &lt;- should be 4c
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j21n6h1v/2/) for convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.  I found some posts online that suggested resets in a pseudo selector don't work.  I moved them out and it now works as expected. This doesn't appear to affect the increment, however.

```
div.panel-body > div.item {
  counter-increment: item;
  counter-reset: sub-item;
}

div.panel-body > div.item:before {
  content: "Item " counter(item) ". ";
}
```

here's the working solution [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j21n6h1v/5/)

Comment: Yes, your problem was indeed because of the sub-item counter being reset under the `div.item:before`. The `:before` element is a child element of the `div.item` and so its value is known only to that element. The next `div` (which is the `.sub-item`) doesn't know about the existence of this counter or its value (doesn't inherit it) and so every `.sub-item` creates a sub-item counter of its own and sets to `a`. When you reset the counter at `div.item`, the value of that counter is inherited by all its siblings and so each `.sub-item` can increment to b, c and so on.

Comment: You may find the detailed explanation in this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658111/how-do-i-stop-div-tags-interfering-with-counters/31660287#31660287 ) helpful. I don't think it is a dupe because the cases are a bit different but you'll understand more about how counter scope and inheritance works.