# How do I stop <div> tags interfering with counters multiple levels of headings?

Tags: html, css, css-counter

This is an expansion of [How do I stop <div> tags interfering with counters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658111/how-do-i-stop-div-tags-interfering-with-counters)

The accepted answer solves the problem for one level of headings (ie H1 in the question) but not if there are multiple levels of headings (see below)

```css
body {
  counter-reset: h1 h2 h3 h4;
}
h1 {
  counter-reset: h2 h3 h4;
}
h2 {
  counter-reset: h3 h4;
}
h3 {
  counter-reset: h4;
}
h1:before {
  counter-increment: h1;
  content: counter(h1)"  ";
}
h2:before {
  counter-increment: h2;
  content: counter(h1)"." counter(h2)"  ";
}
h3:before {
  counter-increment: h3;
  content: counter(h1)"."counter(h2)"."counter(h3)"  ";
}
h4:before {
  counter-increment: h4;
  content: counter(h1)"."counter(h2)"."counter(h3)"."counter(h4)"  ";
}
div:before {
  content: counter(h1)"."counter(h2)"."counter(h3)"."counter(h4)"  ";
}
```

```html
<div>
  div
  <h1>H1</h1>
  <h2>H2</h2> 
  <h3>H3</h3>
  <h4>H4</h4>
  <h4>H4</h4>
  <h4>H4</h4>
</div>
<div>
  div
  <h4>H4</h4>
  <h4>H4</h4>

</div>
<div>
  div
  <h3>T1</h3>
  <h3>T1</h3> 
</div>
```

As can be seen from the above snipped not all the counters are inherited between the divs. Is There a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

**replace:**

```
h1{counter-reset: h2 h3 h4;}
h2{counter-reset: h3 h4;}
h3{counter-reset: h4;}
```

**with**

```
h1{counter-reset: h2 initial h3 initial h4 initial;}
h2{counter-reset: h3 initial h4 initial;}
h3{counter-reset: h4 initial;}
```

```css
body {
  counter-reset: h1 h2 h3 h4;
}
h1 {
  counter-reset: h2 initial h3 initial h4 initial;
}
h2 {
  counter-reset: h3 initial h4 initial;
}
h3 {
  counter-reset: h4 initial;
}
h1:before {
  counter-increment: h1;
  content: counter(h1)"  ";
}
h2:before {
  counter-increment: h2;
  content: counter(h1)"." counter(h2)"  ";
}
h3:before {
  counter-increment: h3;
  content: counter(h1)"."counter(h2)"."counter(h3)"  ";
}
h4:before {
  counter-increment: h4;
  content: counter(h1)"."counter(h2)"."counter(h3)"."counter(h4)"  ";
}
div:before {
  content: counter(h1)"."counter(h2)"."counter(h3)"."counter(h4)"  ";
}
```

```html
<div>
  div
  <h1>H1</h1>
  <h2>H2</h2> 
  <h3>H3</h3>
  <h4>H4</h4>
  <h4>H4</h4>
  <h4>H4</h4>
</div>
<div>
  div
  <h4>H4</h4>
  <h4>H4</h4>

</div>
<div>
  div
  <h3>T1</h3>
  <h3>T1</h3> 
</div>
```

Comment: Nothing against your answer, you seem to have found out (what I think is a) bug and you've also got a solution to it, so a +1 from me for your efforts. However as you can see the last `h4` element within the first `div` outputs the correct counter values even in the snippet in question and so as per specs, the next `div` should also inherit these values correctly (because the `h4` is the ***immediately preceding element in document order***). This inheritance seems to be failing and the effect is getting propagated further down.

Comment: @Harry. When determining **immediately preceding element in document order** , does it matter that the elements are not siblings? (In the snippet the `hX` elements are all children of the `div` elements). I do agree that it may be a bug as the fist counter in the `div` is carried over correctly.

Comment: Yes @Marked. They needn't be siblings. I took it from the [W3C Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-lists/). Under Example 17 it says this *However, rather than inheriting the value 1 from "foo" along with the counter, in inherits the value 2 from "bar", the previous element in document order*. even though 'baz' is not a sibling of 'bar'.